# How to style child elements of innerHTML?

Tags: reactjs

I am looking to style the child elements in the `innerHTML` of a `ref`. For e.g. in the below I want to style the `div` with `id="one"` in green color. How can I go about doing this via either external css, inline styling, or any other styling method?

I am receiving this HTML from a trusted external source so don't have a way to style the html directly. I also need a way for the id to be colored to be a variable (i.e. could be "one, "two", or "three" in the below)

```
import './styles.css'


export default function RefTest(props) {

    const aRef = useRef()
    const html = `<div id="one">I am in 1</div><div id="two">I am in 2</div><divid="three">I am in 3</div>`

    useEffect(() => {
        aRef.current.innerHTML = html
    })

    return (
        <div ref={aRef} />
    )
}
```

I have tried the stylesheet approach below but that doesn't seem to work.

```
.one{
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: ... why? if you _truly_ trust your HTML source (and if there's a MITM chance, then you probably can't) can you not use [dangerouslySetInnerHTM](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) on that div instead? (if the html has the right CSS class, then your `.one` should kick in just fine). Ideally instead you'd build your component based on getting a state (e.g. json data) that you build your component up from. Not as-arbitrary-as-it-can-get HTML.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, but the reason I am looking to do this is that I need to change the style of individual divs in the innerHTML based on user interaction. For example if the user were to click on one of the divs, I need to highlight that to a different color.

Comment: yeah, I asked the wrong question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style something with an ID of `one` you would use the ID selector, not the class selector.

Like so:

```css
#one {
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way for the ID selector "#one" to be a variable? For example if the user were to click on one of the divs, I need to highlight that to a different color. But I won't know which div id that would be until the click has happened so my css would somehow need to take in a variable for the ID selector.

Comment: You can have a `<style></style>` in your innerHTML and set the contents of that to whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

First problem, you should use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)  instead of `innerHTML`.

Second, `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` doesn't apply the style or properties, check [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5616)